# TwilioConversationsClient not returning conversation for SID

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-conversations

I'm developing a chat app in Swift. I am following the Quickstart found here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/ios/exploring-conversations-swift-quickstart#joining-a-conversation

I have 2 devices and I'm trying to get them to join a conversation and chat with eachother. I'm able to successfully get one device into the conversation and sending messagse.

When I launch the app on a 2nd device, and try to join the same conversation, I get an error, but I'm expecting a conversation. Here is the code that returns the error:

```
// uniqueConversationName = "general"

client.conversation(withSidOrUniqueName: uniqueConversationName) { (result, conversation) in
            // Getting an error that informs me that the participant is not part of the conversation
            if let error = result.error {
                print(error)
            }
            
            // Expected to get a conversation, but conversation is nil
            completion(result, conversation)
        }
```

The conversation is `nil` and the error is:
`Error Domain=signal.sdk.domain.error Code=50430 "User not participant of conversation" UserInfo={kTCHErrorMsgKey=User not participant of conversation`

I know that the user is not a participant of the conversation yet - I want to retrieve the conversation and then using the `conversation` object, I will join the participant.

With this current state, I can never add a 2nd participant to the conversation.

**Why is this error being thrown and how can I fix this?**

Here is how the first user creates a conversation and joins it

```
func createConversation(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, TCHConversation?) -> Void) {
        guard let client = client else {
            return
        }
        // Create the conversation if it hasn't been created yet
        let options: [String: Any] = [
            TCHConversationOptionFriendlyName: uniqueConversationName,
            TCHConversationOptionUniqueName: uniqueConversationName
        ]
        
        client.createConversation(options: options) { (result, conversation) in
            if result.isSuccessful {
                print("Conversation created.")
            } else {
                print(result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                print("Conversation NOT created.")
            }
            completion(result.isSuccessful, conversation)
        }
    }

conversation.addParticipant(byIdentity: currentUserIdentity ?? "", attributes: nil) { result in
                print("Result of conversation join: \(result.resultText ?? "No Result")")
                if result.isSuccessful {
                    self.loadPreviousMessages(conversation)
                }
            }
```

**Why is this error being thrown and how can I fix this?**

Comment: Make sure your conversation is being created , you can check it on twilio account that you have bought .if the conversation is created between the users the delegate of conversation is called on both ends. Mainly conversation is created with help of backend.